# Search for value in multi map

Tags: c++, c++11, multimap

Suppose I have the following:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int x) {
        _x = x;
    }
    int _x;    
}

int main() {
    multimap<string, Foo> mm;
    Foo first_foo(5);
    Foo second_foo(10);

    mm.insert(pair<string, Foo>("A", first_foo));
    mm.insert(pair<string, Foo>("A", second_foo));

    Foo third_foo(10); 
}
```

What's a nice way of checking if `third_foo` with key `"A"` is already in my `multimap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`multimap::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) to fetch a range of iterators to entries that have the key `"A"`. Then use [`any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) to check if any of those values compare equal to the `Foo` you want.

```
auto const& r = mm.equal_range("A");
bool found = std::any_of(r.first, r.second,
                         [&third_foo](decltype(mm)::value_type const& p) {
                             return p.second._x == third_foo._x;
                         });
```

Answer (score 6):

[`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) can be used to find an object in any container that can be iterated.

In your code it would look like this:

```
auto it = std::find(mm.begin(), mm.end(), std::pair<string, Foo>("A", third_foo));

if (it == mm.end())
    // third_foo is not in the multimap
else
    // third_foo is in the multimap
```

To make this you will either have to add an `operator ==` to `Foo` or use a predicate with `std::find_if`. That would  change your call to look like this:

```
auto it = std::find_if(mm.begin(), mm.end(), 
    [&third_foo](auto v)
    { 
        return v.second._x == third_foo._x;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution could be to use `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` methods, inside a lambda that is immediately:

```
bool found = [mm](const string& key,int expectVal) {
    auto ub = mm.upper_bound(key);    
    return (find_if(mm.lower_bound(key),ub,[expectVal](auto p){ return p.second._x==expectVal; }) != ub);        
}("A",third_foo._x);
```